# Is anyone using perl with ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am very new to ROS...

I am much more familiar with perl than Python, but can't seem to find any information (perl modules, etc...) for interacting with ROS from perl.  Is there a good reason for the lack of perl support (other than no one has done it yet)?

I have been read through the various documents (Technical Overview, TCPROS, Slave_API, etc...) but am having a little trouble understanding exactly what needs to be done to implement the perl code to interact with ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64328/is-anyone-using-perl-with-ros?/) by [bcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/5057/bcarroll/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Mostly, there are no Perl bindings because no one has done it, and it's kind of a lot of work; you have to implement the XMLRPC node API, service clients and servers, topics, and message generation.

I knew Perl and C++ when I started working with ROS, and I picked up enough python to work with ROS fairly quickly.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1